# Применить hover к иконке для смены её цвета

Tags: css3, html5, hover

Привет, есть такой вот код ниже, и нужно когда навожу на кружок, чтобы менялся его цвет, я пробовала, но у меня что-то не получается.

```css
#footer{
 text-align: center;
 background: #f7f7f7;
 height: 260px;
}

.circle_icons{
 margin: 50px 300px;
}

.circle_soc_icon{
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px 16px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #d3d3d3;
 border-radius: 50px;
}

.copy{
 font-size: 17px;
 padding-top: 12px;
}

.circle_icons:hover {
 color: #ff6e47;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="button" href="#">Contact Us</a>
   <div class="circle_icons">
    <div class="circle_soc_icon">
     <i class="font fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="circle_soc_icon">
     <i class="font fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="circle_soc_icon">
     <i class="font fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="circle_soc_icon">
     <i class="font fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
   <div class="copy">© 2015 - 2016 Deviserweb Ltd.</div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Смотря какие вы иконки используете. Это изображения? Шрифт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо color используйте background-color

```
circle_soc_icon:hover {
    background-color: #ff6e47;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я так тоже пробовала, но видимо допустила где-то ошибку и забросила этот вариант.

Comment: если вам помог мой ответ, тогда отметьте его решением, пожалуйста =)

Comment: Это не совсем то что хотел ТС.

Comment: "нужно когда навожу на кружок, чтобы менялся его цвет"

Answer (score 1):

Вы не у тех блоков меняете цвет, вам необходимо менять его у `.circle_soc_icon`

```css
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  height: 260px;
}

.circle_icons {
  margin: 50px 300px;
}

.circle_soc_icon {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 16px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.copy {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}


/* Это нам не надо, мы меняем цвет не у блока а у внутренних элементов.
.circle_icons:hover {
  color: #ff6e47;
}*/

.circle_icons>.circle_soc_icon:hover {
  color: #ff6e47;
}

.circle_soc_icon>i {
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</script>
<section id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="button" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <div class="circle_icons">
      <div class="circle_soc_icon">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="circle_soc_icon">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="circle_soc_icon">
        <i class="fab fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="circle_soc_icon">
        <i class="fab fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">© 2015 - 2016 Deviserweb Ltd.</div>

  </div>
</section>
```